# How to change the Gradiant color of a State Layout

Tags: android, colors, gradient, background-color

Im trying to change programmatically the background of my activities using this drawable file using this one :
My question is how do I change the starColor and the endColor with java in the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/startColorBackGround"
            android:endColor="@color/endColorBackGround"
            android:angle="90"
            android:type="linear"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

this is the layout of my activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout > 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/activity_main_background"
android:id="@+id/activityMain"
tools:context="org.example.wordgamealpha.MainActivity">
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I change the startColor and the endColor in the drawable file xml in java in my activity